# How to compute MAP estimate of y?

Tags: estimation, parameter-estimation

Suppose that a scalar random variable y is of the form $y=z+v$, where the pdf of $v$ is $p_{v}(t)=\frac{t}{2}$ on the interval $[0,2]$, and the pdf of $z$ is $p_{z}(t)=2t$on the interval $[0,1]$. Both the densities arezero elsewhere. There is available a single measurement value y=2.5.
How to compute the maximum a posteriori estimate of y? I obtained the $pdf$ of $y$ is equal $\frac{y^3}{6}$ on interval $[0,2]$ and zero elsewhere.

Can anyone help me to compute this?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some mistake in your problem set-up.  As it stands the PDF of y is fully known - typically estimation is used to estimate unknown parameters.  The MAP estimate for a variable with a known distribution I would take to be just the value of that variable that maximizes its PDF.

The fact that you are given a measurement for y is irrelevant since you know the distribution of y itself - knowledge of a sample from the fixed distribution does not change the distribution.

Assuming there is not a mistake in this setup, then apparently you need to find the maximum likelihood value of y, given the distribution of y, which is simply the value of y that maximizes its PDF.

The MAP estimate is given:
$$
argmax_yP(\text{Data}|y)P(y) \\
=argmax_y\text{Constant}P(y)
$$
since the previous data sample is independent of the next data sample from that distribution.

To do this find the maximum of your the PDF of y - I would suggest plotting it first.